# BouncingScrollPhysics not working with "shrinkWrap: true"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `ListView` with `shrinkWrap: true`.

Also, I have applied `BouncingScrollPhysics()` to the `ListView`

The problem is bounce physics only works at the bottom of `ListView`. When I scroll to the top, it doesn't show the bounce effect.

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem right now with a ListView.separated; it will only bounce at the bottom. Did you find a solution for it?

Comment: @FrancisCajalne haven't found a solution yet

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
  child: Column(...),
)
```

Comment: This doesnt work on ListView.. It still bounce on the bottom only

Comment: @JayVDiyk That's why I didn't use `ListView`, I know it won't work there.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, I just used `physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(parent: BouncingScrollPhysics())`

Comment: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()) worked

Answer (score 4):

`BouncingScrollPhysics()` does not always work if the `ListView` is not 'full'. For example if the `ListView` needs 5 items to fill its view and become scrollable, then the `BouncingScrollPhysics()` will probably only work when the `ListView` contains 5 or more items.

Comment: It works only at the bottom of ``ListView`` at the top it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using NeverScrollableScrollPhysics into the ListView.builder.

But first set the bouncing scroll physics:

```
child: SingleChildScrollView(
physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
```

And in the ListView use both shrinkWrap and physics:

```
ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap: true, physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if above Functions are not works you should use this one  `physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),`

Comment: But that's what the question is about! They _already_ applied `BouncingScrollPhysics()` and _it's not working_.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).